# Answered - JavaFX: SubScene won't focus inside TabPane when clicked?

Tags: java, javafx, focus, scene

It seems like the behavior of **SubScene** or **TabPane** isn't what i was expecting or something is wrong with it.

**Because** Instead of Being Focused on **Subscene** *[*1.]* when i **click on Subscene** it focuses on **TabPane**. Even when i force it to focus on the **SubScene** it forces back & focuses on **TabPane** *[*2.]*

1. *(Is in grey color & it is inside a tab)*
2. *(as seen on Debug console, 3rd GIF)*

#### Replicating the Issue:

*(How to test the issue by yourself)*

- Add a **TabPane** & a **Tab**
- Add a **SubScene** Inside the **Tab**
- **Check** By Clicking On SubScene Where it Focuses By Printing:

```
  SubScene.getScene().getFocusOwner().getId();
```

[Main.java](https://pastebin.com/h7kGrdbX) | [Controller.Java](https://pastebin.com/nf9tJfQW) | [sample.fxml](https://pastebin.com/CHjY5iHw) | ***(Or just  Copy Paste)***

.

#### Issue Effect:

| *sub*-**scene** |

[image]

| *sub*-**scene**.getScene() |

[image]

Comment: Key events are delivered to the node that has the focus. Events also travel down the scene graph to the target and then bubble back up to the window. If the neither sub-scene nor any of its descendants have the focus then the key event won't reach the sub-scene. Also, in the case a descendant has the focus, if the key event is consumed before reaching the sub-scene then the sub-scene again won't receive the event.

Comment: @Slaw i get the fact that `"Key events are delivered to the node that has the focus ...also travel down the scene graph"` but isn't supposed to be focused on sub-**scene** when i already have clicked on the layout of sub-**scene**? _(because it doesn't focus, it seems like it works only for nodes down the sub-**scene**'s graph and not for sub-**scene** itself)_

Comment: to give you an idea, when i set `scene.requestFocus();` on **MouseEvents** and then observe the behavior of focus-Event it seems like when i click on the layout of sub-**scene** it **loses** focus and then **gains** it back each time i click on it...

Comment: * *(i've updated my post with one more gif for that)* *

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. Unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: @kleopatra I think it was minimal and demonstrated the problem well enough untill i came accross "other" issues and i added the **[Extra info]** section for that reason, but still you are right i have to reedit it somehow ...,  for now though  i have not that much time to do it... `please learn java naming conventions` i'm gonna try more if i was wrong anywhere...

Comment: * *(ReEddited)* *

Comment: My first comment was general information since I don't know enough about your application to provide more specific help. When asking a question like this (_Why isn't this code working?_) you need to provide a [mre] (← read link). You currently describe a problem, give a vague description of the scene graph structure, and provide some GIFs as proof the problem exists. However, you haven't actually provided any code for us to look at and try ourselves. Please _create_ an example application that demonstrates the problem and then [edit] it into your question—as formatted text, not images.

Comment: * *(ReEddited, Done)* *

Comment: Try `scene.setOnMousePressed(e -> { scene.requestFocus(); e.consume(); })`. If the mouse-pressed event reaches the tab pane (or something related to the tab pane, not sure) then it requests focus. And regarding naming conventions, variables use `camelCase`.

Comment: @Slaw What kind of **sorcery** is this ```e.consume();``` it actually works , you have made my day **Thanks you very much!** because whenever i stack on an issue most of the times it is like i can't continue and do anything else unless i find out the reason [...]

Comment: But the real question is ```should that thing actually be happening or not?```

Comment: Yes, the behavior makes sense. If the mouse is pressed somewhere inside a tab and none of the nodes consume the event then the tab pane should become focused. To understand more about event processing, such as what `consume()` does, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/events.htm