# Create a first person camera in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, camera

While trying to create a first person camera in javafx I tried to set the rotationAxis to a new Point3D with the translate Coordinates of the camera.
That did not work so I started searching on stackoverflow, since I only recently installed javafx I am not yet comfortable with it and therefore had no idea how to even attempt to fix the problem.
Anyways I found the following thread concerning the matter:

[How would I make a first person camera in JavaFX 3D?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35021784/14909278)

However if I copy this code and implement the proposed fix I still do not get a proper first person camera, so any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Below is a simple example code demonstrating the problem.

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.PerspectiveCamera;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.SubScene;
import javafx.scene.control.Slider;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.paint.PhongMaterial;
import javafx.scene.shape.Box;
import javafx.scene.transform.Rotate;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    Box box = new Box(150, 150, 600);
    SubScene sub = new SubScene(new Pane(box), 600, 600);
    PhongMaterial mat = new PhongMaterial(Color.RED);
    PerspectiveCamera cam = new PerspectiveCamera();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        sub.setCamera(cam);

        cam.setRotationAxis(Rotate.Y_AXIS);

        box.setMaterial(mat);
        box.setManaged(false);
        box.setTranslateX(300);
        box.setTranslateY(300);
        box.setRotationAxis(Rotate.X_AXIS);
        box.setTranslateZ(100);

        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.sizeToScene();

        Slider slider1 = new Slider();
        slider1.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(cam.rotateProperty());

        pane.setCenter(sub);
        pane.setBottom(slider1);

        stage.centerOnScreen();
        stage.show();

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: _" I still do not get a proper first person camera_" please explain what do you expect and what do you get

Comment: @c0der With the current code, the camera seems to rotate around x = 0 (if you rotate it around the y-Axis). I however want it to rotate around itself. That means, that you should not be able to see an object which you currently cant see, because it is blocked by another object by rotating around either axis. Like I said, it should behave like a first person camera, like in any first person game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/FXyz/FXyz/blob/master/FXyz-Core/src/main/java/org/fxyz3d/scene/SimpleFPSCamera.java

Its been a while since we updated it but it should get you started.

Comment: Trank you, I will look into that!